# How to prevent rendering a new component next to the button after button click

Tags: reactjs, button

I have a button when I click it, it will render the other component's data (i.e., getting data from API) in present component. But it is rendering next to the button:

```
<Button variant="contained" color="primary" style={{marginLeft: 80 , marginTop: 35 , marginBottom: 10}} onClick={this._onButtonClick}>
  Search
</Button>
{this.state.showComponent ?
  <NewComponent A = {this.state.a} B = {this.state.b} C = {this.state.c} D = {this.state.d}/> : null
}
```

Actually this button is in the div's right side in Horizontal manner (left side there are some searching filters some dropdowns & datepickers) but I want to render the component data below this searching filters. Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** I am assuming that you rendered Button and NewComponent at the same place like in your snippet. Please share the full component for a better understanding of your problem.

You have to move the `NewComponent` outside of the div that has all the search filters and button.

```
...
<div>
  // ...search filters
  <Button variant="contained" color="primary" style={{marginLeft: 80 , marginTop: 
    35 , marginBottom: 10}}
   onClick={this._onButtonClick}
 >
   Search
 </Button>
</div>

{this.state.showComponent ?
   <NewComponent A = {this.state.a} B = {this.state.b}
   C = {this.state.c} D = {this.state.d}/> : null
}
```

Comment: Hey got it. Thanks. It got worked after i removed the NewComponent from the same div where i have search filters. Thank you.